# Can you specify your own attribute used to name a tap/click action in DataDog React Native SDK?

Tags: react-native, datadog

The [DataDog docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/browser/tracking_user_actions/#declare-a-name-for-click-actions) states that

> Starting with version 2.16.0, with the `actionNameAttribute` initialization parameter, you can specify your own attribute that is used to name the action.

Thus you can have something like this in the DD configuration constructor:

```
DD_RUM.init({
    ...
    trackInteractions: true,
    actionNameAttribute: 'itemID',
    ...
})
```

Now both attributes `itemID` and `data-dd-action-name` can be used to name tap/click actions; `data-dd-action-name` is favored when both attributes are present on an element.

However that seems to be the case only for the browser SDK, and not the React Native SDK. Is this really the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-dd-action-name` is currently the only way to specify the target name of an action using the RUM React Native SDK.

Depending on your use case you may can also use the `DdRum.addAction()` and `DdRum.startAction()` methods for manual action tracking and provide the desired target name. There is an example of calling these methods in the [Manual Instrumentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/reactnative/advanced_configuration/#manual-instrumentation) section of the [RUM React Native SDK documentation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/reactnative/).

Comment: With manual action tracking, do I need to specify the name of each button I'm tracking even if each button uses the same attribute?

Comment: @uzluisf I believe the name is required as part of the method call when manually triggering an action.

Comment: At the risk of being too pedantic, what does `button name` refer to? Let's say I've `<TouchableOpacity buttonID='referral-link'></TouchableOpacity>`, does `button name` refer to `TouchableOpacity`, `buttonID`, or `referral-link`?

Comment: The string `button name` is an example of the name you'd like the action to have.  In your example, I would guess you would want `referral-link`.

Answer (score 0):

The `accessibilityLabel` attribute does what you are looking for ([source](https://docs.datadoghq.com/real_user_monitoring/mobile_and_tv_monitoring/setup/reactnative/#user-interactions-tracking)). I'm not sure whether `dd-action-name` counts as a valid attribute in React Native.